# Setting input type="datetime" set via javascript in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I have a Date object in JS and I'm trying to set the value of . But I just can't seem to figure it out. In IOS nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the heading relate to the text of the question? An `input type="datetime"` element is quite different from a Date object.

Answer (score 3):

The issue that I think you are referring is setting an input field in iOS 5 of type datetime. Like this one:

```
<input type="datetime" id="dateStart" />
```

the only way I found is to use the toISOString() formatting method

```
var currentTimeAndDate = new Date(); 
document.getElementById('dateStart').value = currentTimeAndDate.toISOString();
```

or in jQuery

```
$("#dateStart").val(currentTimeAndDate.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an environment that I can test, however the [HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.date.html) says that your input should be like:

```
<input type="date" name="someDate" id="someDate">
```

The value should be returned as a string in the format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

I expect that you should be able to convert that to a date object using:

```
var date = new Date(document.getElementById('someDate').value);
```

in browsers that support input type date. But likely other browsers will use the page too (and will require an on-screen hint as to the appropriate format), so you may want to parse the date manually, something like:

```
var dateBits = document.getElementById('someDate').value.split('-');
var date = new Date();
date.setYear(dateBits[0], dateBits[1] - 1, dateBits[2]);

// Validate the date
if (date.getFullYear() == dateBits[0] && date.getDate() == dateBits[2]) {
    // got a valid date
} else {
    // didn't get a valid date
}

// And if the time needs to be zeroed
date.setHours(0, 0, 0);
```